# How to get data from Form from child component and pass it back to Parent Componet?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add items to the lists.Items come from Child Component's form .

```
class App extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    lists: [],  // this holds the name of each list
      };
  }

  handleAddList(s) {
      this.setState({lists:s});
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What should I write in handleSubmit function such that it return list to parent component?How to access input's value from form element?

```
class AddList extends Component {   

  handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      this.props.addList(e.target.value);  //Isn't this the way to get input from Form ...//
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="addListDiv">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <div id='addList'>
      <label>What will be on your next list?&nbsp;
      <input type='text' ref='id' id='newID'></input>    //How ref is used?????
      </label>
      </div><br />
      <input type='submit' value='Create List' />
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: For instrustions on how to use `ref` in React look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: dont use string literals for refs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your input value by ref you can use `this.refs.id.value` and to pass value from child to parent component you can use props.

```js
let {Component} = React;

class App extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lists: [],  // this holds the name of each list
      };
    }

    handleAddList(s) {
      this.setState(prevState => {
       return {lists: [s, ...prevState.lists]}
      });
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
          {this.state.lists.map((name, i) => <div key={i}>{name}</div>)}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

class AddList extends Component {   
    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      let name = this.refs.id.value;
      if(name) {
       this.refs.id.value = '';
        this.props.addList(name); 
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div id="addListDiv">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <div id='addList'>
        <label>What will be on your next list?&nbsp;
        <input type='text' ref='id' id='newID'></input>   
        </label>
        </div><br />
        <input type='submit' value='Create List' />
        </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you explain me this code and Can't we write this.setState({lists:s}); INSTEAD of this
      this.setState(prevState => {
       return {lists: [s, ...prevState.lists]}
      });

Comment: If you do this you will set value of lists to your current s value instead of adding it to array, `[s, ...prevState.lists]` this will create new array where it will first add you new input value or s and then "spread" or add old values from list, also if you want to access old state inside setState you should pass function as i did.